# Do something every nth iteration of loop in Objective-c or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, loops

Within a loop, it is possible to do something every other time by using odd and even and testing for even. I would like to do something a fixed number of times eg four  no matter how many iterations there are in the loop (value of i). Is there a way to do something every nth time?

I think there must be a way by incrementing a second counter, but having trouble getting it.

```
A Loop
int i = 0;
int movinglimit = 0;
int incr = [myItems count]/4;;// there might be 10, 20 or 30 items. I only want to do something four times
while (i < [myItems count]) {
    
if ((i % 2) == 0) {
    
//do something if even
}


 if (i>movinglimit) {
        //do something a total of four times
 }
 if (i==moving limit+1) {
            movinglimit = movinglimit + incr;
 }
    i++;
 }
```

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Can you give an example? You know about `i % 2` so what's the problem? Can you give examples of how many iterations there would be and which iterations the "thing" should happen on? As you say, let the fixed number be 4. Which iterations should have the "thing" if there are 9, 11, 12, 13, 18, 245 iterations? What's the "right" answer? If you say that, then it is possible to say how to achieve it.

Comment: The event should happen "every nth iteration of loop".  Someone perhaps you has edited my question, but in contrast to every other oe 2nd, I would like to get every nth.  Was it really necessary for you to downvote it 3 times?

Comment: @user6631314 users can only downvote once/question, so there are 3 users thinking this one is a replica or something. Just do not become nervous. See voting more as a kind of sorting tag of millions of questions that have been asked. I personally do not like the downvoting culture unless the question is really lazy. In my opinion SO is also good to get feedback and improve your learning curve while others see it more as a compendium of correct answers.

Comment: maybe you could share your object type/definition (class model / generic) of myItems array, you could get thrilling answers.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. If you know about `i % 2 == 0` you know about `i % n == 0`.

Comment: I didn't know about 1 % n but now that you mention it, it makes sense

Comment: Ol Sen. An  innocuous question like this might receive one downvote from someone with a view of what questions should look like but three suggests malice--from one person controlling multiple accounts or a "group" that follow one another.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *myItems* is an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` or `NSSet` you can apply methods on all objects at once which is smarter than implementing an iteration looping thru object by object yourself. That way you take full advantage of objC.

```
[myItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(yourObjectMethodToApply)];
```

This has the side effect that **nothing** is done/applied **if myItems** is **nil**

A short comment on your pseudocode.
Be careful with **while** loops without any increment inside.
The one you show here is *only* looping once.

```
//iteration backward
NSUInteger i = myItems.count-1;
for ( ; i>0; ) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
         // do stuff if 4th is even

    }
    // do stuff on every 4th one

    i-=4; //increment does not have to be in for () declaration
}
```

identify the similarity (also backward iteration) to

```
NSUInteger i = myItems.count-1;
while (i>0) {
    // do stuff on each 4th item

    //check for odd/even
    myItems[i] = i % 2 ? /* even stuff */ : /* odd stuff */;

    i-=4; //decrement i
}
```

Comment: woops. (i>0) may not access index 0 of your array, so it should be (i>=0)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged Swift so I assume you want Ob-C or Swift answers. You can enumerate the loop and use that enumeration (which I call `n` below). The first enumeration will always be `0`, of course, so to simplify the even/odd parity, just add `1` to make the first iteration `1`.

```
let data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

for (n, i) in data.enumerated() {
    if (n+1).isMultiple(of: 2) {
        print(n+1, i) // every even iteration
    }
}

// output: 2 b, 4 d, 6 f, 8 h, 10 j

for (n, i) in data.enumerated() {
    if (n+1) <= (4*2), (n+1).isMultiple(of: 2) {
        print(n+1, i) // every even iteration but only 4 times
    }
}

// output: 2 b, 4 d, 6 f, 8 h
```